# Re-branding ceramic tea/coffee mugs

Tags: ceramics

I have been given a set of unused standard straight-sided coffee mugs with an out-of-date brand on them. 
The branding appears to have been screen-printed on then fired, so its impossible to remove (It's made from glaze)

I want to either cover this up with another brand or remove it. 
the new finish must be dishwasher safe, or removable (a sleeve?)

Is this possible? What with?

Answer (score 4):

If you have a vinyl cutter, or are patient enough and talented enough to manually cut out your new brand from adhesive vinyl, there are several which are both dish-washer and food safe.

There are also dish-washer safe acrylic paints but I don't know how food safe they are.

Comment: Thank you - I do have a vinyl cutter actually, I wasn't aware there was any dishwasher-proof vinyl, will have a look! Not sure if "Food safe" is really as issue as its external only.

Comment: I did a quick amazon search for dishwasher safe vinyl and got several hits, one of which had a testimonial in its comments which stated that that particular product had survived 5 wash cycles with no signs of wear.  Thanks for the idea of restyling my coffee cups.